# How to fix UTF-8 / locale problem in openSUSE Linux (in terminal / file names and program dialogues)

Tags: opensuse, locale, unicode

I have some file / folder names which are not 7-bit clean and they are not displayed correctly in my openSUSE system.

Example for the folder /music/Gabriel_Fauré:

```
# ls -1d /music/Gabriel_Faur?
/music/Gabriel_Faur??
```

Perhaps the locale for `LC_CTYPE` is not set to some UTF-8 value?

```
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=a4
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Well, that's a nice `LC_CTYPE` for Unicode, I think!  What does the error message say?

Funnily enough, setting `LC_ALL` to the exact value of `LC_CTYPE` will work:

```
# setenv LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
# ls -1d /music/Gabriel_Faur?
/music/Gabriel_Fauré
```

However, **I do NOT want to set LC_ALL** to en_US.UTF-8 (or anything, really) because it messes up some other settings!   It would be no fix but only a bad workaround for me.

Also, why is LC_CTYPE ignored by `/bin/ls` and/or my shell when printing characters to the screen?

In Arch Linux I would check whether locales are generated but I found nothing on the subject in openSUSE.  Also, the locale does seem to exist.

EDIT:

```
# ls -1d /music/Gabriel_Faur? | hexdump -C
00000000  2f 6d 75 73 69 63 2f 47  61 62 72 69 65 6c 5f 46  |/music/Gabriel_F|
00000010  61 75 72 c3 a9 0a                                 |aur...|
00000016
```

So it's correct UTF-8 (as far as I can tell).

EDIT2:

```
# locale -a | grep en_US
en_US
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
# locale -a | wc -l
495
```

EDIT3 (after correct Answer):

```
# unsetenv LC_PAPER
# unsetenv LC_ALL
# ls -1d /*/Gabriel_Faur?
/music/Gabriel_Fauré
```

The `LC_PAPER=a4` variable prevents UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters from being printed (no pun intended) *on screen*!

Comment: What does `echo /music/Gabriel_Faur?|hexdump -C` print?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What that *`locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory`* message tells you is that one of the locales you're trying to use doesn't exist.  It's not about the `$LC_ALL` environment variable, `locale` is just reporting an error when the `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` call it does to initialise localisation based on environment variables returns NULL indicating a locale configured via one of the various `LC_*/LANG` variables cannot be found.

Here, since it works with `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` which overrides all the other ones, the problem must be with `LC_PAPER=a4`. `a4` is not the name of a valid locale on your system and is causing `setlocal(LC_ALL, "")` to fail.

When `setlocale()` fails, the behaviour defaults to the C locale, where the character encoding is ASCII. In the C locale, every byte is a character but 0xc3 and 0xa9 are unknown ones as they are not in ASCII, so `ls -q` (and `-q` is enabled when the output goes to a terminal) renders them as `?`.

You can see the list of available locales on your system with:

```
locale -a
```

You probably won't find a `a4` in there. If you want the paper size to be A4, where `locale -k LC_PAPER` outputs:

```
height=297
width=210
paper-codeset="UTF-8"
```

You'll probably want to use a European locale for `$LC_PAPER`, something like `en_GB.UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the Question, please look at the output. Still: Why does LC_ALL setting work?

Comment: @Ned64. OK I had missed that. That's most probably caused by that `LC_PAPER`, see edit.

Comment: You are right, it is the paper size - but why do the UTF-8 characters not appear when the printer's paper size is a4?

Comment: @Ned64, It's not about the _printer paper size being a4_, it's about one of the `LC_*` variables being set to an invalid (unknown) locale (here `LC_PAPER` set to `a4`). There is no locale on your system called `a4`. Locales are typically not named after paper types. `locale -a | grep -x a4` will return nothing. As I said use `LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8` or any other locale where the paper size is that of A4, not LC_PAPER=a4.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. It did seem illogical but of course I know it wasn't as this is a computer, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `locale` can be fixed in OpenSuse with:

`zypper in glibc-locale`

I needed this to use a `en_GB` locale while building a `MicroOs` image with `kiwi`

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know but unfortunately not helpful in this case (see the accepted Answer).